# Is the Eclipse RCP "Window > Show View" menu predefined somewhere

Tags: eclipse, rcp

I am trying to understand Eclipse RCP to maintain an Eclipse application. I created a template example with the "RCP 3.x application with a view" wizard. It opens a bare window with a single view, no toolbar, no nothing. A tutorial showed me how to add a basic "File" > "Exit" action like so:

plugin.xml

```xml
<extension
      point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
   <menuContribution
         locationURI="menu:org.eclipse.ui.main.menu">
      <menu
            label="File">
         <command
               commandId="org.eclipse.ui.file.exit"
               label="Exit">
         </command>
      </menu>
   </menuContribution>      
</extension>
```

The mechanism is clear enough. Now I want to add the "Window" > "Show View" action that all other Eclipse products I know of (Java, PDE, J2EE) have. The application that I'm trying to get into also has it, and it doesn't seem to define it anywhere in any of its' components' `plugin.xml`s. So, is there some native Eclipse plugin that defines the "Window" menu and this action? Where would I find it? I'm pretty baffled by how hard it has been to find any information on this. I've found a few things from which I could piece together how to manually create this action, but that isn't what I want.

Comment: The standard menu items are added in the `ActionBarAdvisor` for the RCP - for Eclipse this is `org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.WorkbenchActionBuilder`. in the `org.eclipse.ui.ide` plug-in.